How to patch a function with pytest-mock regardless of path/namespace used to call it?
I am trying to mock a function regardless of how it is imported in the code.
I can't find info on how to do it.
Here is an example, the first assert works as expected but the second fails because path:
import mymodule
from mymodule import test1


def test_mock(mocker):
    mocker.patch('mymodule.test1', return_value="mocked")
    assert mymodule.test1() == "mocked"  # works
    assert test1() == "mocked"  # fails


That won't work. You have to mock in the namespace where you are using the object. You are using it in two different namespaces.

@KlausD. thank you, I was hoping it was possible.
I added a related question, do you know? Thanks.

Only one question is allowed per question.

Sorry, removed related question.

patch redefines names, not the values names refer to. test1 and mymodule.test1 are two different names for the same object. The patch only changes one of those names; the other still refers to the original value. That's why the first argument has to be a string, not an expression that evaluates to an object.

You have to modified the second test as following:
with patch("__main__.test1", return_value="mocked_2"):
    assert test1() == "mocked_2"

In the previous code, the instruction:
with patch("__main__.test1", , return_value="mocked_2"):
is used to mock the name test1 in the namespace of the the test file.
I have saved your production code in the file mymodule.py where it is defined only the function test1():
def test1():
    return "real test1 function"

My complete test code is saved in the file test_module.py, and its content is the following:
import unittest
from unittest.mock import patch
import mymodule
from mymodule import test1

class MyTestCase(unittest.TestCase):

    def test_mock(self):

        # this is your working test
        with patch('mymodule.test1', return_value="mocked"):
            print("Test 1")
            assert mymodule.test1() == "mocked"  # works

        # THIS IS YOUR SECOND NOT WORKING TEST CHANGED TO WORK
        with patch("__main__.test1", return_value="mocked_2"):
            print("Test 2")
            assert test1() == "mocked_2"

        # ... here I have not used MOCKING
        print("Test 3")
        assert test1() == "real test1 function"

if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()

Below I shows the output of the execution of the method test_mock() defined in test_module.py:
Test 1
Test 2
Test 3
.
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 1 test in 0.001s

OK

In the output you can see the printout Test 1, Test 2 and Test 3 showing the execution of 3 calls of test1() (with and without mocking).
NOTE: I have not used pytest; I have used only the module unittest.
